# why is Glassfish 3.1 admin console unloaded?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

After deployment of a big .ear application on a fresh GF 3.1 server, the admin console is gone. Instead, I get the "Your server is now running" page, the same as when you open a web page from port 8080 on a new domain.

The .ear application has about 20 ejb-jar and war modules.

Restarting the domain brings the admin console back on port 4848.

Any clue?

Comment: Anything useful in the server.log?

Comment: Not sure: because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327070/why-does-mojarra-2-1-scan-every-other-war-on-each-module-startup there is too much noise to see anything useful. As I solved this, I hope to have more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are seeing similar issues reported in  http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15905 and  GLASSFISH-16223.
The fix is available in the 3.1.1 promoted build,  you can download from http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/3.1.1/promoted

Anissa.

Comment: It looks like 16223. However, it's a production environment, I don't want to try anything experimental there. A support engineer told me that he'd try to get a patch for 3.1. When will 3.1.1 be available, btw?