# why does mojarra 2.1 scan every other war on each module startup?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, mojarra

We have a huge EAR application with about 20 ejb-jar and war modules.

For each war module that Mojarra starts, it seems it is trying to scan annotation on every other war. Other wars are unavailable to the classloader, so I get lot of exceptions. It eventually starts anyway, but it clutters my logs with warnings, and I guess application startup time could be much less without this (+100 seconds).

To make it clear, I have following structure:

```
EAR
+- ejb1
+- ejb2
+- war1
+- war2
```

When Mojarra starts war1, it complains about missing classes from war2 (ClassNotFoundException).

I saw this when upgrading to Glassfish 3.1 (and thus, Mojarra 2.1).

Comment: Open an issue against GlassFish Server 3.1.  It should get forwarded to the right person on the Mojarra team for evaluation.

Comment: OP opened an issue against Mojarra 2.1 http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1995 which in turn is retargeted to GF 3.1.

Comment: interested in any workaround, we are going to use that in production and I could really use faster startup / less log noise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason, and some workaround.

On Glassfish 3.1, which ships with Mojarra 2.1, classpath scanning is delegated to Glassfish. Now, Glassfish seems to give all classes of ear file instead of war. I opened http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1995 for that (but it really seems to be a Glassfish bug, not JSF/Mojarra).

While waiting for a fix, I patched Mojarra like this : in com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.java, around line 834, I commented out some lines:

```
//            if (provider instanceof DelegatingAnnotationProvider &&
//                null != annotationScanner) {
//                // This InjectionProvider is capable of annotation scanning *and*
//                // injection.
//                ((DelegatingAnnotationProvider)provider).setAnnotationScanner(annotationScanner,
//                        metadataGetter.getJarNames());
//                scanUris = Collections.emptySet();
//            } else {
                // This InjectionProvider is capable of annotation scanning only
                scanUris = metadataGetter.getAnnotationScanURIs();
//            }
```

The logs are now much less verbose. It seems Glassfish is still scanning every classes, so I still get warnings like this:

```
[#|2011-03-18T13:47:05.019+0100|WARNING|oracle-glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.org.glassfish.web.loader|_ThreadID=57;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|WEB9052: Unable to load class org.apache.myfaces.custom.inputTextHelp.HtmlTextHelpRenderer, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.myfaces.custom.inputTextHelp.HtmlTextHelpRenderer|#]
```

But no stacktrace from Mojarra, which is already quite less verbose.

Comment: Startup time isn't better yet :-(